syncfusion rich text editor vue image upload
how can I load an image into my vuex action and get the value of image ?   Can't load via vuex!Is it possible to download via vuex? look at the screenshots
enter image description hereenter image description hereenter image description here
<template>
    <ejs-richtexteditor ref="rteObj" :quickToolbarSettings="quickToolbarSettings" :height="340" :toolbarSettings="toolbarSettings" :insertImageSettings="insertImageSettings">
    </ejs-richtexteditor>
</template>

<script>
import { RichTextEditorComponent, Toolbar, Image, Link, HtmlEditor, QuickToolbar } from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-richtexteditor";
import { mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
    components: {
        'ejs-richtexteditor': RichTextEditorComponent
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['pushPicture']),
        handleImageUpload(files) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.pushPicture(files)
                    .then(response => {
                        resolve(response);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
                        reject(error);
                    });
            });
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            height: 400,
            quickToolbarSettings: {
                image: [
                    'Replace', 'Align', 'Caption', 'Remove', 'InsertLink', 'OpenImageLink', '-',
                    'EditImageLink', 'RemoveImageLink', 'Display', 'AltText', 'Dimension',
                ]
            },
            toolbarSettings: {
                items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'StrikeThrough',
                    'FontName', 'FontSize', 'FontColor', 'BackgroundColor',
                    'LowerCase', 'UpperCase', '|',
                    'Formats', 'Alignments', 'OrderedList', 'UnorderedList',
                    'Outdent', 'Indent', '|',
                    'CreateLink', 'Image', '|', 'ClearFormat', 'Print',
                    'SourceCode', 'FullScreen', '|', 'Undo', 'Redo'
                ]
            },
            insertImageSettings: {
                saveUrl: this.handleImageUpload,
                removeUrl: 'https://ej2.syncfusion.com/services/api/uploadbox/Remove'
            }
        };
    },
    provide: {
        richtexteditor: [Toolbar, Image, Link, HtmlEditor, QuickToolbar]
    }
}

how can I load an image into my vuex action and get the value of image ?   Can't load via vuex!Is it possible to download via vuex? look at the screenshots.
This is vuex for upload picture
import axios from "./axios"
    
    export default {
        actions: {
            pushPicture(context, data) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    axios
                        .post('media_objects', data,{
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                            }
                        })
                        .then((response) => {
                            context.commit('updatePicture', response.data)
                            resolve(response.data)
                        })
                        .catch(() => {
                            reject()
                        })
                })
            },
        },
        mutations: {
            updatePicture(state, media) {
                state.media = media['@id']
            },
        },
        state: {
            media: {
                id: ''
            }
        },
        getters: {
            getPicture(state) {
                return state.media
            },
        }
    }


The selected image in the RichTextEditor can be uploaded to the required destination by using the controller action. Map the method name in saveUrl property of insertImageSettings and provide required destination path through path property. Please check the code and sample attached below,
Code snippet:
<ejs-richtexteditor
              ref="rteObj"
              :insertImageSettings="insertImageSettings"
              :quickToolbarSettings="quickToolbarSettings">
             </ejs-richtexteditor>


 data: function () {
    return {
      insertImageSettings: {
        saveUrl: 'https://localhost:44342/api/RichTextEditor/SaveFile',

        path: 'https://localhost:44342/images/',
      },
}

Server-side code:
public void SaveFile(IList<IFormFile> UploadFiles)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (IFormFile file in UploadFiles)
        {
            if (UploadFiles != null)
            {
                string filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                filename = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\images" + $@"\{filename}";

                // Create a new directory, if it does not exists
                if (!Directory.Exists(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\images"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\images");
                }

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(fs);
                        fs.Flush();
                    }
                    Response.StatusCode = 200;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 204;
    }
}

Stackblitz-sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/heqyyk?file=src%2FApp.vue

My image is loaded via vuex

I changed the question, look again
